# What happens to the Apparatus of Kwalish when it runs out of HP?

Tags: dnd-5e, magic-items, objects

I just read the entry on the Apparatus of Kwalish in the DMG. There is nothing that says what happens to the vehicle when it runs out of hit points.

**Does it regain hit points? If so, how? Or is it destroyed? What happens to it when it is destroyed?**

Answer (score 21, accepted):

### It is destroyed like any other object

The Apparatus's description says that it is a large object. As explained in the DMG (and basic rules) section on [objects](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/dmg/running-the-game#Objects):

> When characters need to saw through ropes, shatter a window, or smash a vampire's coffin, the only hard and fast rule is this: given enough time and the right tools, characters can destroy any destructible object.

When it makes sense to do so, the DM can assign statistics to an object to determine how hard it is to destroy:

> When time is a factor, you can assign an Armor Class and hit points to a destructible object.

Of course, the description of the Apparatus already specifies its AC and hit points. As for what happens when those hit points are depleted:

> ***Hit Points.*** An object’s hit points measure how much damage it can take before losing its structural integrity.

In other words, when an object's hit points are reduced to 0, the object is destroyed. The rules don't say exactly what "destroyed" means beyond the vague explanation of "losing its structural integrity", because that is highly dependent on the nature of the object and how it is being damaged. That means the exact consequences of a object's destruction must be determined by the DM. For example, destroying a section of wall might mean making a hole in it so that creatures can pass through, or it might mean that the roof supported by that wall collapses; destroying a statue might simply mean breaking it in half, or it might mean shattering it into small pieces. However, in general, a destroyed object can no longer fulfill its function, and in particular, a magic item that is destroyed is no longer a magic item.